# Error message while trying to create PDF in R Markdown

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown

I'm trying to create a PDF in R Markdown and I keep getting this error message every time I try to click "Knit to PDF":

```
  output file: test_4_for_r.knit.md


Output created: test_4_for_r.pdf
Error in tools::file_path_as_absolute(output_file) : 
  file 'test_4_for_r.pdf' does not exist
Calls: <Anonymous> -> <Anonymous>
In addition: Warning message:
In readLines(logfile) : incomplete final line found on 'test_4_for_r.log'
Execution halted
```

I do not have a lot of familiarity with RStudio, so I have no idea why I'm getting this message.  I've read several things online saying creating PDFs in R Markdown requires several packages, but so far I've only found the name of knitr.  That is the only one I have currently installed.  I'm not sure if that is the issue or not.

Can someone please point me in the right direction on how to remedy this?  Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: This look similar to a GitHub issue.  [This comment](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/1285#issuecomment-374340175) contains the fix, I think, but the whole thread might be of interest.  Another related thread [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/rmarkdown-knit-pdf-issues/10102), which may contain some helpful info.

Answer (score 0):

In R-Studio Tools > Global Options, under the Sweave tab, try changing "Weave Rnw using:" from sweave to knitr. Also try

```
install.packages('tinytex')
tinytex::install_tinytex()
```

and then try to knit your PDF.

If those don't work, please paste the markdown code giving you trouble. Could you knit the example markdown file, found when you File > New File > R Markdown?

Comment: The first option didn't work.  With the second option, the first line installed it, and the second line comes up with an error.  I have MikTex installed.  Is that an issue?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with MikTex with R... I've just had good luck with tinytex which is why I suggested it. You could try re-installing R Studio and starting with very simple markdown documents and adding complexity from there